# VueJs - How can i call an event when the cursor focus out in the combobox field

Tags: vue.js

I have a combobox field in the screen and i need to call an event when i click on save button after typing a new text in this combobox field which is not currently available in the dropdown list.

My seniors told me to use focusout event to get this, but i don't know how to get this.

I am using combobov.vue to show dropdown

Please help me out.

Comment: needs to be more specific with code

Comment: <v-combobox v-if="autocomplete == false" :autocomplete="!browserAutocomplete" @mouseover.native="tooltipIcon = true" v-model="record[fieldName]" :ref="fieldName"  :disabled="readonly || disabled" :items="dropdown"  :attach="attach"@change="_dpChange" @keyup.enter="_dpChange"item-value="value" :label="title" v-bind:class="{ 'required': (required == true),                  'column-selected': (inline == true && this.$store.state[this.parentName].formData.indexOf(record) != this.$store.state[this.parentName].formData.length - 1))}"return-object> code in combobox.vue

Comment: Need to add a focusout event in above code

Comment: I think you should use `@blur` event

Comment: @blur="_dpChange" is it correct format?

Comment: `@change` is called when you type or you select an option, @blur called when you leave the input

Comment: so, this will call whenever i tried to enter any words or after i click in outside field

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Boussadjra Brahim I think its work with @blur .. thankuu

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" found in ---> <VCombobox> This error is getting in console after using @blur event. Did i missed out something? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix issue by using @blur. Thanks everyone for the comments, especially Boussadjra Brahim